# Не работает автоматическое приведение к типу структуры при выносе конструктора из объявления структуры

Tags: c++

Имеется три файла `main.cpp` `A.cpp` `A.hpp`. Сами файлы:

> main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    A a_obj(1, 1);
    a_obj += 1;
    cout << a_obj.m_a << "\t" << a_obj.m_b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> A.hpp

```
#ifndef AHPP
#define AHPP

struct A
{
    A(int a, int b);

    A & operator+=(A const &a_obj);

    int m_a;
    int m_b;
};


#endif
```

> A.cpp

```
#include "A.hpp"

A::A(int a = 1, int b = 1)
{
        m_a = a;
        m_b = b;
}


A & A::operator+=(A const &a_obj)
{
    m_a = m_a + a_obj.m_a;
    m_b = m_b + a_obj.m_b;
    return *this;
}
```

При попытке скомпилировать получаю следующую ошибку

```
tempmain.cpp:8:11: error: no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types are ‘A’ and ‘int’)
```

При этом если определить конструктор внутри структуры, то срабатывает автоматическое приведение от `int` к `A`. С чем связано такое поведение?

Comment: "При этом если определить конструктор внутри структуры...". Не "определить конструктор внутри структуры", а "указать значения аргументов по умолчанию в определении структуры". Почему вы их оттуда убрали?

Comment: Да, я осознал своё непонимание. Теперь мне стало ясно, что если я хочу задать функции аргументы по умолчанию, то это следует делать в объявлении функции, а не в её определении. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

А что вы ждете здесь:

```
a_obj += 1;
```

Что тут должно вызваться? Если вы надеетесь на то, что 1 превратится в объект `A` - с чего бы, если есть конструктор только от *двух* `int`ов... Если вы укажете на

```
A::A(int a = 1, int b = 1)
```

то эти значения по умолчанию вы показываете только в `A.cpp` и при компиляции `main.cpp` компилятор о них ничего не знает. Такие вещи обычно пишут в объявлении, а не в реализации...

А оператора `+=(int)` у вас и в самом деле нет...